# Firefox is acting sluggish

Tags: 12.04, firefox

I am having problems with running Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04. I am finding it to be sluggish at times. The symptoms I experience are:

- At times temporary freezing of the screen when trying to scroll up or down.
- Randomly certain tabs wont load at all and need to be manually refreshed.
- Additionally at times tabs wont load completely and only parts of the page load.
- Also, on the Firefox health report, in the past 5 days I've had 4 crashes recorded.

My system specs are:

- ubuntu 12.04
- 6gb ram
- 24gb ssd with operating system on it
- 1tb hdd for media with symbolic links to the home directory
- intel i5-3317U @ 1.70GHz × 4
- Intel® HD Graphics 4000
- firefox version 27.0.1

Any help given will be greatly appreciated.
Thank  You

Answer (score 1):

The best way to recover your firefox is a cleanup of your profile. **Close firefox**, open a terminal and type:

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla-backup
```

to clean up your firefox session. Launch firefox again and check if the issue persists.

If it worked, you can recover your old history and bookmarks by copying the database in ~/.mozilla-backup/firefox/xxxxxxxxxxx.default/places.sqlite to your new ~/.mozilla/firefox/profile (xxxxxxxxxxxx are numbers are letters generated by firefox to your current user/session), browse it with nautilus to see yours.

Remember that the more extensions you add, the more functionallities, but also the more resources and potential missfunctions.

Comment: This is a rather  efficent way of refreshing Firefox, an alternative would be to close Firefox and run this to edit the profiles: `firefox -P`. Note the profiles contain internet history, logins & saved passwords, cookies, etc as well as the extensions.

Comment: Where would I find the Mozilla-backup file? its not in /usr/lib or /usr/bin where i expected it to be? thx

Comment: @mike100111 the backup of your entire profile will be in your home folder, as a hidden folder. Press CTRL+h in nautilus to enable the hidden files. Then browse to .mozilla-backup in your home. | Notice that you will never find personal data at system level (or definetively you shouldn't), so /usr/ is not the place to look for. FYI /usr/bin just host the "executables" at system level, whilst lib, the libraries for that binnaries. No personal data at all there. In fact, if you enter "sudo" basically you shludn't be referring to any user data, but system level things.

Comment: @Wilf indeed profiles management do that. However for seek of ease on implementation this method is way more direct. Notice that if you change the profile (i.e. create a new one) you will have to tell firefox to open the new profile each time, having to modify the launcher too (to make it permanent and natural to use). To do that an edition of /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop is needed, clearly complicating things cause this is just a user-level clean up solvable thing. Otherwise, the selection of profiles should be carried each time running ff... really inconvenient imho. :)

Comment: It's not that complicated - you either edit `profiles.ini`, or use the dialogue - wait a sec...

Comment: yap, it's not complicated at all. But above is one line, no interaction. if @mike100111 is curious can also play with that option: Mike, you can create multiple profiles by running "firefox -P" in a terminal (instead of lauching your firefox from the icon). Profiles can handle different extensions and separate the history/bookmarks per profile. You may choose your default profile from there too (I had some inconsistencies with that in the past, but probably they fixed it, that's why I mentioned the firefox.desktop mod before). ANyway, that's another choice that does escentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

As in @Rho 's answer, if you move the profile folder, it will remove extensions etc. there are other ways to implement this.

<sub>If you have already followed Rho's answer, which should work nicely anyway, you can run the following to restore the Firefo profile:</sub>

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozillaX
mv ~/.mozilla-backup ~/.mozilla
```

<sup>This will move the folder that would of been created if you have opened Firefox since, then restore the original.</sup>

Now, you can open Firefox, and enter the following in the address bar:

```
about:addons
```

By disabling all the unnecessary extensions, it should hopefully speed up Firefox.

---

Now, for a different implementation of Rho's answer, close Firefox and run:

```
firefox -P
```

Then you can use this dialogue to add profiles:
[image: firefox -P window]

Create a new profile, and select it. make sure 'Don't ask a Startup' is selected otherwise it gets annoying, and then click <kbd>Start Firefox</kbd>

At anytime, you can close firefox and switch profiles using `firefox -P`.